# Default date not using the system time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model user with a migration that says

```
add_column :users, :performed_something, :date, :default => Date.today (also tried Time.now.getlocal)
```

hitting up the console shows me that

```
Time.now.getlocal
=> 2014-03-11 07:42:51 -0700  (which is correct)
```

but doing this

```
 u = User.new
 puts u.performed_something
 => Mon, 10 Mar 2014
```

Seems to be giving me the previous date when in fact they are calling the same type of method. I've also checked the system date and it says PDT but I'm not really sure if that's where the issue lies.

Comment: You can't do this in Rails. Check the `schema.rb` - it will set the default to whatever time you ran the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning the same date over and over again because `Date.today` is only evaluated once. To fix this, put the default values in the User model, something like:

```
after_initialize :set_defaults

def set_defaults
  if new_record?
    self.performed_something ||= Date.today
  end
end
```

This will set the `performed_something` attribute if it's value is still `nil`.

Comment: You will need to roll back the migration too, otherwise the default date will still be 2014-10-03

Comment: thanks for this, I can't roll back the migration though since there are existing data already, I just added a new migration to change the column and remove the default.